# How to export WebM and h264 from a Mac

Tags: video, quicktime

I exported two videos from Photoshop using the standard export movie tool. The dialog is the standard Quicktime Export that we're used to seeing from the beginning of times.

For each movie I chose the WebM (QT Extension) and h.264 as a codec. Both file names come out with a .mov extension, but are encoded with their appropriate codec.

Their final destination is a website, where they will be embedded with the html5 video tag. If I manually change their extension to .webm and .mp4, will they work when I upload them to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a free app in the Mac App store, Miro Video Converter. It might do what you need.

Comment: I would add: first export to a lossless format such as Animation and then pass it through Miro to the desired formats and codecs.

Comment: I would add: Miro Video Converter is $14.99.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it, mov webm and mp4 are all container types and renaming mov files to different container types is a recipe for disaster

You could always leave them and add type and codec hints to the video tag HTML markup

Comment: Indeed, the .mov to .mp4 didn't have any problem on any platform, but .mov to .webm refused to play in anything except Chrome.